# How to enable concurrency checking using EF 5.0 Code First?

Tags: c#, entity-framework-5, optimistic-concurrency

I would like to do a check-then-update in an atomic operation. I am using dbcontext to manage the transaction. I was expecting to get an exception if the record has been modified by another thread but no exception is thrown. Any help would be appreciated. Here's my output:

```
Thread-4: Reading...
Thread-5: Reading...
Thread-5: Updating destination 1
Thread-4: Updating destination 1
Thread-4: SaveChanges
Thread-5: SaveChanges
```

Here's my code snippet:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    PopulateData();
    (new Thread(UpdateDestination1)).Start();
    (new Thread(UpdateDestination1)).Start();
}

public static void UpdateDestination1()
{
    using (var context1 = new BreakAwayContext())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Thread-{0}: Reading...", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        var d = context1.Destinations.FirstOrDefault();
        Console.WriteLine("Thread-{0}: Updating destination {1}", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, d.DestinationId);
        d.Name = "Thread-" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        try
        {
            context1.SaveChanges();
            Console.WriteLine("Thread-{0}: SaveChanges", Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);
        }
        catch (OptimisticConcurrencyException)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("OptimisticConcurrencyException!!!");
            throw;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can use ConcurrencyCheck annotation on a property ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg193958.aspx ) or IsConcurrencyToken() or .IsRowversion when configuring a property with fluent API ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj591617#1.12). Typically you would have a rowversion column in the database.

Comment: "vote up" is different from "mark as answer".  The first is an arrow (upwards) and the other is a checkmark (becomes green after clicking.)